# System::Threading::Mutex, called from unsynchronized block of code. Unexpected deadlock

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli, ipc, mutex, deadlock

In an attempt to rid my GUI of race conditions and deadlocks I have the following function which I call from the c'tor and whenever I need the service which shares my named `mutex` to provide its input:

```cpp
void EnvCapt::FireServiceAndOrHold() {
    try {
        mutTimerSyncEx->ReleaseMutex();
        Thread::Sleep(100); //Time enough for the service to complete.
        if (!mutTimerSyncEx->WaitOne(3 * int_ms)) {//int_ms = the polling period
            //Must've been doubly locked or worse.
            mutTimerSyncEx->ReleaseMutex();
            FireServiceAndOrHold();
        }
    } catch (Exception ^ ex) {
        //Released unheld mutex. Retake control.
        mutTimerSyncEx->WaitOne();
        FireServiceAndOrHold();
    }
}
```

This works relatively well but I am calling this before letting the service now I am ready to accept input so it never attempts to wait for me to release the mutex for it. Before I attempt to re-order things I would like to know what is going wrong with the above function. The error I get is:

> Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.

Because calling release on a `mutex` that hasn't been `WaitOne`'d will throw I catch that, knowing I am free to take ownership of it and continue. But I am wrong. It hangs forever on the `WaitOne()` statement. I know what the other process is doing all this time because it is trapped in my second debugger window. It is not touching the mutex.

**UPDATE**

I've attempted the reordering I first suggested, this seemed good but now I find that the mutex is only sort of Global, despite having a Global\name.

- It *is* shared because when my GUI c'tor's it `firstInstance` is false, hence I attempt to take control of it.
- It is *not* shared because when the GUI calls `WaitOne()` on it the GUI blocks indefinitely. Whereas the service dances straight through its call to `WaitOne()` without a care in the world.

Comment: why are you using synch primitives, and second guessing it ('must have been double locked...' and 'knowing I am free to take ownership of it and continue' -> it doesn't work that way. You can NEVER know 'you are free to take ownership' unless you _are holding the mutex locked_. The rest is just an 'enhanced' race condition (the mutex may have been locked while you received the exception). Also, exceptions are for _exceptional_ situations.

Comment: If I release a shared named mutex, and it throws, this can only mean it is not locked. Therefore I am free to take ownership. Exceptions happen all the time in some situations and must be cleaned up if that is the only way to solve the problem. Please, this is .NET and not C++-CLI specific, the translation is minimal when we are dealing with such high level concepts as mutex and sync'ing. Or, whatever, just give my code back its color!

Comment: nope. You just defined a race condition. It may have been locked in the mean time. Also, there is absolutely no need to catch exception on releasing a mutex you don't hold, because you can always know whether you already held it. This is what I meant with 'exceptions are for exceptional situations'.

Comment: No, not locked by anything I can't see. I have a debugger on both processes' threads, there are breakpoints on practically every line.

Comment: The race condition that sehe is describing is one where you checked the status of the lock and then tried to take it. Between those two actions, _another thread may have already taken it._ Just because you know that another thread did not _currently_ do so doesn't mean that it's not possible during further executions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had an idea what might be going wrong for you there:

*Hint*: you cannot release a mutex on behalf of the other process! The other process will have to release the mutex if it holds it:

```
Process 1:                           Process 2:
============                         =============

    WaitOne (locks the mutex)

    // do work                       WaitOne (awaits the mutex)

    // do more work

    // done
    ReleaseMutex         ------>     WaitOne returns from the wait _with 
                                             the mutex locked_
```

Comment: I can release a shared, globally named mutex on behalf of another process, otherwise, what would be the point of sharing? They wouldn't sync. Hmm, I see where I may have broken it. Perhaps thus far they had all been releasing their own locks, but that doesn't sound like sharing if each has separate locks. Don't think I've got time to check that tonight though. Can you link to some evidence of what you describe?

Comment: @John: what would be the point of holding a lock if another process could release it _on your behalf_? Please read up on synchronization primitives first. **edit**: I think you want **[name Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms906887.aspx)**

Comment: As for the evidence: your question seems to carry it. **Edit** I see your edit now. Take it easy, good luck bug hunting tomorrow!

Comment: You most definitely cannot release resources that you don't own. What would be the point of locking something if someone else can just remove your lock in the middle of what you were doing?

Comment: Ah heck I'm just adding new race conditions with all my breakpoints. So much for my real time system. Thanks guys. Sorry if I caused any offence, had some late nights this week and got chilled to the bone to boot. Nice, question as evidence +1